# Proof of $G\rightarrow G/H$ is a Principal H bundle

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Let $G$ be a Lie group and let $H$ be a closed subgroup (not necessarily normal). Then $G$ is a principal $H$-bundle over the (left) coset space $G/H$.

I could proof that the fibers are all isomorphic to H

Let $\pi: G \rightarrow G/H$ be the canonical map

$\pi^{-1}({x+H})=\{g\in G | g+H=x+H\}=\{g\in G | g^{-1}.x\in H\}$

We can define a map $\pi^{-1}({x+H})\rightarrow H$ via sending $g$ to $g^{-1}.x$.

It can be easily checked that the map is a homeomorphism.

Therefore, fibers are homeomorphic to $H$.

***But I am not able to see why $H$ is the Structure group.***

Lets take two distinct fibers $\pi^{-1}({x+H})$ and $\pi^{-1}(y+H)$ (i.e., $x^{-1}.y\notin H)$

Multiplying by $y.x^{-1} $ will send element of $\pi^{-1}({x+H})$ to element of $\pi^{-1}(y+H)$. But then $ y.x^{-1}  $ doesn't belong to $H$.

For G to be a principal $H $ bundle over $G/H$ the structure group has to be $H$ and $H$ acting on fiber $H$ be left multiplication.

Comment: It's not correct to say that the fibers are "isomorphic to $H$," because they don't have any natural group structure. But they are all _diffeomorphic_ to $H$.

Comment: $H$ acts on the fibers by *right* multiplication.

Comment: What is the action?

Comment: Yes, I should have written diffeomorphic.

Comment: @Babai: the action is by right multiplication. This is essentially the definition of $G/H$: it's the quotient of $G$ by the action of $H$ given by right multiplication.

Comment: If H is the structure group then H is should act on the fiber. What is the action on the fiber?

Comment: @Babai: the action is by right multiplication. I don't know how to be any clearer than this. The fiber over the coset $gH$ is $\{ gh : h \in H \}$ and if $h' \in H$ then the action is $gh \mapsto gh h'$. (If your definition of a principal bundle requires that the structure group act on the left, you should revise it: it's cleaner to have it act on the right.) The actual difficulty in this question is showing that the bundle is locally trivial; everything else is formal.

Comment: Take two fibers over $gH$ and $g'H$. The  fibers are $\{gh:h\in H\}$ and $\{g'h:h\in H\}$. Now what is the element of H which will send one fiber to the another?

Comment: The action you have given is the H acting on a single fiber? I am asking how does H moves a fiber to another fiber? An element of a structure group sends a fiber to a different fiber.

Comment: @Babai: Actually, no. The structure group acts on the _model fiber_ (on the left), and each transition function for the bundle must be given by a function into the structure group, acting on the model fiber on the left. In the case of a principal bundle, the structure group also acts on the total space on the right, but it takes each fiber to itself, not to another fiber. See my answer below. In this case, the only group action that moves one fiber to another is the action of $G$ on itself by left multiplication; but $H$ is the structure group, not $G$.

Answer (score 7):

Part of the confusion here is that in any principal $H$-bundle $\pi\colon P\to M$, there are two different $H$-actions:

1. There is a free *right* action of $H$ on the total space of the bundle, whose orbits are the fibers of $\pi$.
2. There is also the left action of $H$ on itself by left multiplication, which shows up in the transition functions for the bundle. To say that $P$ is a principal $H$-bundle means that there is a covering of $M$ by open sets $\{U_\alpha\}$ together with local trivializations $\Phi_\alpha\colon \pi^{-1}(U_\alpha) \to U_\alpha \times H$, each of which is a diffeomorphism, and such that whenever $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\ne\emptyset$, there is a smooth *transition function* $\tau_{\alpha\beta}\colon U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\to H$ such that for all $(x,h)\in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\times H$, 
   $$
   \Phi_\beta\circ \Phi_\alpha^{-1}(x,h) = (x, \tau_{\alpha\beta}(x)h),
   $$
   where $\tau_{\alpha\beta}(x)$ acts on $H$ by left multiplication. This is what it means to say the *structure group of $P$* is the group $H$ acting on itself by left multiplication.

In the special case in which $P=G$ and $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$, the right action of $H$ on $G$ is just ordinary right multiplication, and $M = G/H$ is a smooth quotient manifold. The local trivializations are obtained as follows: Given any $x_0\in G/H$, because $\pi\colon G\to G/H$ is a smooth surjective submersion, it has a smooth local section $\sigma\colon U\to G$ (i.e., smooth map such that $\pi\circ\sigma=\operatorname{id}_U$) defined on some neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$. If we define $\alpha\colon U\times H\to \pi^{-1}(U)\subset G$ by $\alpha(x,h) = \sigma(x)g$, then it is straightforward to show that $\alpha$ is a diffeomorphism, so we can define a local trivialization $\Phi\colon \pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times H$ by $\Phi = \alpha^{-1}$.

Given any other such local section $\sigma'\colon U'\to G$ and corresponding maps $\alpha'$ and $\Phi'$, a computation shows that $\Phi'\circ\Phi^{-1}(x,h) = (x,\sigma(x)\sigma'(x)^{-1}h)$. Thus each transition function is given by $\tau(x) = \sigma(x)\sigma'(x)^{-1}$, acting on $H$ by left multiplication.